# dynamic table numbers php

Tags: php, for-loop, if-statement

I still don't get how to create a dynamic table using PHP.

I would like to display a table with a variable amount of columns and rows containing numbers between 1 and 200.

[Example of the expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMaLe.png)

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Your friend here is going to be the [modulo operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) (`%`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A nested loop within an outer loop should do it - the outer loop controlling the rows and the inner loop controlling the columns.

```
$rows=20;
$cols=10;
$x=1;

$html=array();
$html[]="<table>";
for( $i=0; $i < $rows; $i++ ){

    $html[]="<tr>";
    for( $j=0; $j < $cols; $j++ ){
        $html[]="<td data-cell='r{$i}c{$j}'>$x</td>";
        $x++;
    }
    $html[]="</tr>";
}

$html[]="</table>";


echo implode( PHP_EOL, $html );
```

To cease creation when a pre-defined limit is reached

```
$rows=100;
$cols=10;
$x=1;
$limit=200;



$html=array();
$html[]="<table>";
for( $i=0; $i < $rows; $i++ ){

    $html[]="<tr>";
    for( $j=0; $j < $cols; $j++ ){
        $html[]="<td data-cell='r{$i}c{$j}'>$x</td>";
        $x++;
        if( $x > $limit ) break;
    }
    $html[]="</tr>";
    if( $x > $limit ) break;
}

$html[]="</table>";


echo implode( PHP_EOL, $html );
```

Comment: ok - required curly braces around vars ~ that piece cane easily be removed

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

for($i=1;$i<=30;$i++) {

  echo "*$i*";
  if($i%10==0){
    echo "<br>";
  }
}
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](https://eval.in/924626)